# Mongoid: has_many relation with alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

**BACKGROUND:** I have a Team model which has_many Players, which allows for one to call

```
@team.players
```

and receive a Mongoid::Relations::Targets::Enumerable list of Players back.

OBJECTIVE: I'd like to also be able to retrieve a list of players at a specific position on a team. For instance, if a user adds a pitcher to his team, I'd be able to call 
`@team.pitchers` to return an Enumerable list of pitchers. Any ideas on how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

cant put conditions in has_many in mongoid.

two ways i can think of doing this is set a scope in players and call using @team.players.pitchers

```
Class Player
  scope :pitchers, where(:position => "pitcher")
end
```

or define a method in team

```
Class Team

  def pitchers
    self.players.where(:position => "pitcher")
  end
end
```